# Obtener función de substracción y suma iterativas dentro de un mismo array

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un array como que sigue:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
```

Paso 1: ahora, dado un valor inicial, por ejemplo 100, quiero sustraer a este valor el primer elemento de a. Es decir:

```
100 - 1 = 99
```

Paso 2: ahora, deseo multiplicar este resultado por 0.01. Es decir:

```
99 * 0.01 = 0.99
```

Paso 3: ahora, deseo sumar el resultado de los pasos 1 y 2. Es decir:

```
99 + 0.99 = 99.99
```

Paso 1, de nuevo: ahora, deseo sustraer a este valor el segundo elemento del a. Es decir:

```
99.99 - 2 = 97.99
```

Paso 2, de nuevo: ahora, deseo multiplicar este resultado por 0.01. Es decir:

```
97.99 * 0.01 = 0.9799
```

Paso 3, de nuevo: ahora, deseo sumar el resultado de los pasos 1 y 2. Es decir:

```
97.99 + 0.9799 = 98.9699
```

Y así sucesivamente.

El objetivo es obtener un array que contenga en el mismo orden, los valores obtenidos en el paso 3. Es decir:

```
[100, 99.99, 98.9699 ...]
```

Comparto el ejemplo mínimo de lo que estoy intentando, dentro de una función un poco más compleja:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]) 
b = (100 - np.cumsum(b))
c = b * 0.01
resultado = b + c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que para este problema la forma más directa es hacer un bucle que implemente exactamente lo que describes. Para ello no necesitas numpy, puedes hacerlo con listas "normales" de Python. No se me ocurre forma de lograr lo mismo con una sola línea de numpy que lo haga vectorialmente.

Pero eso sí, a tu descripción se la puede optimizar un poco, ya que donde dices:

- paso 1: sustraer del valor anterior (x) otro valor (y)
- paso 2: multiplicar el resultado por 0.01
- paso 3: sumar los dos anteriores

Realmente puedes decir:

- paso único: computar (x-y)*1.01

Ya que el paso 1 te da (x-y), el paso 2 te da (x-y)*0.01 y el paso 3 te da (x-y) + (x-y)*0.01, que se puede agrupar como (x-y)(1+0.01) y por tanto es lo mismo que (x-y)*1.01

Con esto en mente, el código sería:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
result = [100]
previo = result[0]
for n in a:
  previo = (previo - n) * 1.01
  result.append(previo)
```

y al terminar tienes en `result`:

```
[100.0,
 99.99,
 98.9699,
 96.929599,
 94.86889499,
 91.7775839399,
 88.655359779299,
 85.501913377092,
 82.31693251086291,
 79.10010183597154]
```

Comment: Gracias @abufalia por tu respuesta. Llevo un tiempo sin usar Python y estoy un poco oxidado.